# Generating an HTML table from an mysql pivot table with Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

So, I have 2 tables users and user_meta, the first containing the id, name, email and status and the later key-values for each user (based on users.id). Something like:
users:
    id|name     |mail           |status
    1  UserName  user@smth.com   1
user_meta:
    id| uid  |ukey         |uvalue
    1   1     name          Smith
    2   1     address       something
    3   1     SocialNumber  123456

The problem is to generate a table (with Datatables if its possible) containing all the active users that have a SocialNumber (IS NOT NULL).
The query that I come up with is:

```
SELECT users.id, users.active, uid, 
MAX(IF(ukey = 'name', uvalue, NULL)) AS name, 
MAX(IF(ukey = 'address', uvalue, NULL)) AS address, 
MAX(IF(ukey = 'SocialNumber', uvalue, NULL)) AS SocialNumber, 
MAX(IF(ukey = 'phone', uvalue, NULL)) AS phone, 
FROM user_meta INNER JOIN 
users ON user_meta.uid = users.id 
WHERE users.active = '1' 
GROUP BY uid 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN user_meta.ukey = 'SocialNumber' AND user_meta.uvalue IS NOT NULL 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

This query works but for the life of me I can`t pass the results to Datatables, I guess that the fact that the ids are not consecutive its the problem.

Anybody have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: CREATE new_table as (SELECT...) ?

Comment: Nope, the mofo is HUGE, that`s one of the reasons that the guy befor me choosed Datatables, for pagination...